# Angular 7 exportar PDF

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, pdf, angular7

Tengo un formulario en Angular de varias páginas. Me gustaría exportar el html a PDF unificado por páginas y poder darle estilos, no que salga en el pdf una captura de pantalla de lo que se está viendo.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Está bien que describas cuál es tu objetivo, pero además sería necesario que mostrases cuál ha sido tu progreso hasta el momento, de lo contrario será muy difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Te aconsejo completar el [tour] para entender cómo hacer buenas preguntas que sean bien recibidas.

Answer (score 2):

En mi trabajo tuve que realizar exactamente eso.
Existe la libreria html2canvas, pero descubri que esta podria llegar a ser muy lenta, ya que clona todo el DOM y lo introduce en un iFrame, ademas de esta forma no reconocia a componente hijos de Angular, asi ejecute una de sus funciones y clone todo los elementos del contenedor que necesitaba con los estilos para luego convertilos en imagen y asi pasarlos a un pdf con jsPDF. Es muy posible que esta solucion se lenta pero se podria dejar en service worker.

```
import { DocumentCloner } from 'html2canvas/dist/lib/dom/document-cloner';
import * as jsPDF from 'jsPDF';
import { drawHTML } from 'rasterizeHTML';

const pdf: jsPDF = new jsPDF({
  format:           'letter',
  putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
  unit:             'px',
});
const documentCloner: DocumentCloner = new DocumentCloner(element, {
      id:             (Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) + Date.now()).toString(16),
      ignoreElements: true,
      inlineImages:   true,
      copyStyles:     true,
    });

    documentCloner.documentElement = documentCloner.cloneNode(element) as HTMLElement;
    const elementFrame = documentCloner.clonedReferenceElement;

    const element: HTMLDivElement = elementDom;
    const styleElement: CSSStyleDeclaration = 
    window.getComputedStyle(elementDom);
    const heightPage: number = parseInt(styleElement['height'], 10);
    const widthPage: number = parseInt(styleElement['width'], 10);

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    canvas.width = widthPage;
    canvas.height = heightPage;
    console.time('Rasterize');
    await drawHTML(elementFrame.innerHTML, canvas);

  const dataImage: string = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.width;
    const pdfHeight = (heightPage * pdfWidth) / widthPage;

    pdf.addImage(dataImage, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);

    pdf.save('project_page.pdf');
```

Este fue el codigo que utilice, espero que te sea de utilida, y por mi parte proximamente mejorare esto, ya que es lento y la imagen no es mucha calidad (en mi caso, todo depende de la cantidad de nodos que toque copiar), asi que cualquier contribuccion sera recibida.

Comment: La funcionalidad de un service worker no es la de hacer un trabajo lento y pesado en segundo plano. Todo lo contrario, su reacción debe ser la más rápida posible y delegar las esperas en eventos para no penalizar la experiencia del usuario.